# NetDataContractSerializer produces invalid XML

Tags: c#-4.0, serialization, xml-serialization, netdatacontractserializer

My NetDataContractSerializer seems to be confused: The end of the XML appears twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="1" 

[...]
        <d2p1:anyType i:nil="true" />
      </d2p1:_items>
      <d2p1:_size>2</d2p1:_size>
      <d2p1:_version>2</d2p1:_version>
    </d2p1:items>
  </ProjectParts>
  <ProjectPath z:Id="31">D:\t10\</ProjectPath>
</Project>ze>
              <d2p1:_version>3</d2p1:_version>
            </d2p1:items>
            <d2p1:_monitor xmlns:d7p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.ObjectModel" z:Id="33">
              <d7p1:_busyCount>0</d7p1:_busyCount>
            </d2p1:_monitor>
          </Elements>
          <Project z:Ref="1" i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Modules.WorkspaceManager.Types" />
        </d2p1:anyType>
        <d2p1:anyType i:nil="true" />
        <d2p1:anyType i:nil="true" />
      </d2p1:_items>
      <d2p1:_size>2</d2p1:_size>
      <d2p1:_version>2</d2p1:_version>
    </d2p1:items>
  </ProjectParts>
  <ProjectPath z:Id="34">D:\t10\</ProjectPath>
</Project>
```

As you can see, there is some serious stammering going on. It happens occasionally and I can't reproduce the error. Any ideas? Could it be caused by the file being opened in VS while it's being written?

I serialize my object like this:

```
private void SerializeToFile(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        Stream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = File.Open(_fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
            {
                NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSerialize);
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            if (stream != null) stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

And the class serialized looks like this:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Project : IProject
{
    [DataMember] public string ProjectPath { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public Collection<IProjectPart> ProjectParts { get; set; }

    public T GetPart<T>() where T : IProjectPart
    {
        return ProjectParts.OfType<T>().First();
    }

    public void RegisterPart<T>(T part) where T : IProjectPart
    {
        if (ProjectParts.Any(p => p.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(part))) throw new InvalidOperationException("Part already registered.");
        ProjectParts.Add(part);
        part.Project = this;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        foreach (var projectPart in ProjectParts)
        {
            projectPart.Load();
        }
    }

    public void Unload()
    {
        foreach (var projectPart in ProjectParts)
        {
            projectPart.Unload();
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        foreach (var projectPart in ProjectParts)
        {
            projectPart.Save();
        }
    }

    public Project()
    {
        ProjectParts = new Collection<IProjectPart>();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the class you're trying serialize and how you do it , etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple - when you serialize over and over your object, you do it with different size of `IProjectPart` collection. The `File.Open` method does not clear the file from previous content so assume following steps :

i) serialize object with two `IProjectPart` instaces - let's say it will take 10 lines of xml file

ii) serialize object again with one `IProjectPart` instance in the collection - this time it will take 8 lines of xml file

iii) lines 9 and 10 will be filled with old xml data since they are not cleared between serialization attempts - so there is some duplicated-trash-looking xml data.

Try it for yourself , you will see exactly how those multiple tags are generated.

NOTE : The 8 and 10 lines are approximate values for my implementation

NOTE 2 : I suggest using `using` statement for the stream inside serialization method(as for all IDisposable objects) :

```
private void SerializeToFile(object objectToSerialize)
{
    using(var stream = File.Open(_fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
        {
            NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSerialize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AH! Thank you! I fixed it by cleaning the file with File.WriteAllText(_fileName, string.Empty);... Thanks a lot!